# Integration Runtime automatically updated, and now I can't copy data from onprem location

Tags: azure-data-factory

recently my Microsoft self hosted integration runtime automatically updated and now I can't pull data from my onprem folder and transfer it to a blob storage. The error code I receive is

Error Code  28051

Details     d could not be resolved.
Activity ID: d999e0c0-cb2c-4161-aad5-e01510ca7e8f

Has this happened to any else before?

[image: Error Code Image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had the "d could not be resolved" issue. After being in contact with MS support about the problem, which started when the Integration Runtime was automatically updated to 5.22, they recommended upgrading to 5.23. This did not solve the problem.

However, they also recommended using **fully qualified name** in the linked service that points towards the drive location (host) instead of using a locally mapped name. In other words: **don't use "D:\yourfolder" but "\\servername\D\yourfolder"**. Kind of what "PaulE" also pointed out, I just wanted to highlight that this is also what MS recommends in this case.

Apparently, version 5.22 was the first version where using colon in the path was a problem. Next time, please tell us ahead of such a change, MS ;-)

Comment: Is this answer missing one "\" and one "$" but still accepted as solution? Afaik solution should be `"\\servername\D$\yourfolder`

Comment: @jikuja Sorry, the stackoverflow formatting "stole" a backslash that I have added now. But the $ is not needed. What we have in our Azure Portal is: \\servername\D\yourfolder

Comment: I would use `D$` because that is the actual share name for default share, even `D` might work.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same issue. We downgraded to 5.21; this solved it for us. (also disabled auto-update for now.)

download at:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=39717

Comment: if I downgrade to 5.21, that means I have to delete the integration runtime that I currently have, that is going to mess up my pipelines won't it? Thank you for the response!

Comment: We are using Azure Data Factory and it didn't affect existing pipelines.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has now(2022-11-25) released documentation update and posted health event to affected users.

> Copying files from local machine is not supported under Azure Integration Runtime.
> Refer to the command line from here to enable the access to the local machine under Self-hosted integration runtime. By default, it's disabled. (1)

To enable local disk access there is two solution:

- Use UNC and Windows' builtin file shares. (@PaulE already gave this answer)
- To enable old behaviour running `dmgcmd.exe -DisableLocalFolderPathValidation` should enable old behaviour (2)(3)

---

(1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system?tabs=data-factory#sample-linked-service-and-dataset-definitions

(2) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#set-up-an-existing-self-hosted-ir-via-local-powershell

(3) Health event:

> We have important information regarding your Azure Data Factory V2 resources.

> We have introduced a new security control for the Self-hosted Integration Runtime (SHIR) admin that lets them allow or disallow local SHIR file system access through File system connector. SHIR admins can use the local command line (dmgcmd.exe -DisableLocalFolderPathValidation/-EnableLocalFolderPathValidation) to allow or disallow.

> The latest SHIR version for download can be found here: https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/4/7/E4771905-1079-445B-8BF9-8A1A075D8A10/IntegrationRuntime_5.23.8355.1.msi

> Note: We have changed the default setting to disallow local SHIR file system access from SHIR versions (>= 5.22.8297.1). Using the above command line, you should explicitly opt-out the security control and allow local SHIR file system if needed.

Comment: You can edit the URL to get a specific version

Comment: In the quoted health event? I think that link just should be removed

Comment: no, the URL can be filled with the version number 
download.microsoft.com[...]_<version_to_download>.msi

Answer (score 1):

Same thing here on 5.22 - upgraded to 5.23 and still a problem.
Does your northernmeats connection use a linked service pointing explicitly to the d:\ drive on the machine hosting your IR? We had the same setup (using our c:\ drive) and started getting the same error message - 'c could not be resolved'.

I switched it to using a UNC path like \\MACHINENAME\c$ and it immediately sprang back to life - looks like its specifically related to using the local drive name rather than a share name, so you can workaround it (relatively) easily.

In our case, I wanted to make it a share anyway, so I could throw another IR on another machine on the same net for resilience, a second node, and have it hit the one central folder, rather than the c drive of whichever node happened to fire.
Hopefully this helps anyone in the same boat, and means you're not stuck on 5.21

Comment: what do you mean by UNC path, do I  have to copy the layout you showed here? First time hearing about a UNC path, so I'm curious

Answer (score 1):

We are experiencing the same issue. Accessing local drives C: and D: is not possible anymore since the update to 5.22.

Using the network share path, e.g. \\localhost\c$\, wasn't a solution either. We were accessing many files within a for-loop in parallel and then got errors regarding "max connection limit reached".

Our current workaround is using a relative path.
The SHIR process has its working directory in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Integration Runtime\5.0\Shared\". Therefore replacing "C:\" with ".\..\..\..\..\" was the solution for us.

This won't work for other drive letters than C:, though.

Answer (score 0):

Update the selfhosted IR from here : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39717 and see if that mitigate the issues .

if you are on Windows like me . event logs should give you more info .
[image]

Comment: The link you have provided takes me to the runtime download section, how would that help in this case? My runtime just updated, should I install the runtime again?

Comment: yes try that out and see if that helps . Do you see any error in the error logs ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't work much with ADF, but I know it's similar to Synapse.  Here's what I did in Synapse specifically that works without making any changes to the Integration Runtime or running any commands:

In the Linked Service configuration, set your host to `\\?\`

[image: Edit Linked Service]

Then, in your dataset, you can specify the full path to the folder including C:, D:, etc... I parameterize everything as shown below:

[image: Dataset Connection]

[image: Dataset Parameters]