# Azure DataFactory Linked Service FileSystem Errornr

Tags: azure, filesystems, azure-data-factory

Azure DataFactory File System Linked Service is not working with this error:

Error details
Error code
28051
Details
c could not be resolved.

I tried to connect file excel in onpremise machine using the self hosted integration runtimeg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears that ours auto-updated on 11/11 and it hasn't worked since then for connecting to C drive like it has.

But I've fixed this for myself. have change the Host from `c:\` to `\\servername\c$` and now testing the connection is successful.

Answer (score 0):

I started experimenting this same issue in two different Integration Runtimes after they updated to version `5.22.8312.1`. For some reason I was unable to reach any path under `C:` from Azure Data Factory, but I was able to reach network paths.

I solved the issue mapping the desired local path to a network location, and making sure that the user I'm using to connect has access to that path. After that, I changed the path from `C:\path\to\file.csv` to `\\localhost\path\to\file.csv`. Make sure that this new path works on the local machine before trying in Azure Data Factory.

Answer (score 0):

For those having problems with UNC share paths, you can use the relative path ".\..\..\..\..\" instead of "C:\" as well, as I wrote in this related question: [Integration Runtime automatically updated, and now I can't copy data from onprem location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74394857/integration-runtime-automatically-updated-and-now-i-cant-copy-data-from-onprem/74451926#74451926)